# Binding Checkbox to a run time Boolean property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have that issue where I get the type of a class at runtime, I added a Boolean property to it using `System.Reflection.Emit`, and now i need to bind my DataGridTemplateColumn(Takes Checkboxes) to my property, I've tried many solution and failed, here is my sample code.

ColumnDynamicBuilder.cs:

```
        public ColumnDynamicBuilder(Type typeOfClass)
    {
        myAsmName.Name = "MyDynamicAssembly";

        // To generate a persistable assembly, specify AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave.
        AssemblyBuilder myAsmBuilder = myDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName,
                                                        AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        // Generate a persistable single-module assembly.
        ModuleBuilder myModBuilder = myAsmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(myAsmName.Name, myAsmName.Name + ".dll");

        myTypeBuilder = myModBuilder.DefineType("CheckColumn", TypeAttributes.Public);
        myTypeBuilder.SetParent(typeOfClass);

        PropertyBuilder custNamePropBldr = myTypeBuilder.DefineProperty("CheckBoxColumn", PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, typeof(bool), null);

        // The property set and property get methods require a special set of attributes.
        MethodAttributes getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |  MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

        // Define the "get" accessor method for CustomerName.
        MethodBuilder custNameGetPropMthdBldr = myTypeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_CheckColumn", getSetAttr, typeof(bool), Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator custNameGetIL = custNameGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Define the "set" accessor method for CustomerName.
        MethodBuilder custNameSetPropMthdBldr = myTypeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_CheckColumn", getSetAttr, typeof(bool), new Type[] { typeof(bool)});
        ILGenerator custNameSetIL = custNameSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Last, we must map the two methods created above to our PropertyBuilder to their corresponding behaviors, "get" and "set" respectively. 
        custNamePropBldr.SetGetMethod(custNameGetPropMthdBldr);
        custNamePropBldr.SetSetMethod(custNameSetPropMthdBldr);

        myTypeBuilder.CreateType();

        // Save the assembly so it can be examined with Ildasm.exe, or referenced by a test program.
        myAsmBuilder.Save(myAsmName.Name + ".dll");
        properties = myTypeBuilder.GetProperties();
    }
```

In this part I created a property named `CheckBoxColumn`, and added it to `myTypeBuilder`, along with the static properties found in `typeOfClass`.

Then i wrote a WPF sample for the CheckBoxes to bind, here's the sample code.

ColumnDynamicBuilder.Xaml:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox Content=" Select All"x:Name="cb_HeaderCheckBox" Checked="cb_HeaderCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="cb_HeaderCheckBox_Unchecked" />
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="6 0 6 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_CheckBoxColumn" Click="cb_CheckBoxColumn_Click" IsChecked ="{Binding CheckBoxColumn, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is an error?

Comment: @sTrenat, there are no errors the thing is it is not binding ... I am checking for the properties for a checked row, only the property that I've added at run time (the Boolean) is not showing.

Comment: `"CheckBoxColumn"` and `"get_CheckColumn"`, `"set_CheckColumn"` do not match.

Comment: And you know you can create instances of anonymous types like `var x = new { CheckBoxColumn = false };`?

Comment: Dear @Clemens, thanks for highlighting me the getter and setter name, but still it hasn't changed, and concerning the instance of anonymous types, I am aware of it but not of use in my case. Is there a way to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to bind it?

Comment: @ArnoldDemian, how do you cerate DataContext/binding source to bind dataGrid.ItemsSource? your sample code isn't complete, because it is unclear how data structures and UI markup are wired together

Comment: Dear @ASh, I am not quite sure i understand what you mean, but mainly for the class that I get on run time I am creating dynamic columns, the `properties` presented in  ColumnDynamicBuilder.cs is a list that contain properties name as string, then I am looping on it and create the column with bindings in c# `dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn {Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(prop), Header = prop });` as follow. I tried to do it for the checkboxes still didn't work, is that what you meant?